# Jquery AutoCompletion Limit

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Trying to limit the amount of options in the drop down. My data is in an eternal file. I think the problem is how I reference the source. I think I need to combine these 2 chunks of code. Can anyone help ??

I have a fully working copy of this - however I am trying to limit the number of dropdowns. I dont want to apply a CSS height so I am trying to incorporate a function. The PHP source file (autocomplete.php) is a JSON array.

```
<script>

  $(function() {

    var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 2 //search after two characters
    });
 });


   $("#tags").autocomplete({
       source: function(request, response) {
       var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(myarray, request.term);
       response(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If autocomplete.php loads a javascript array you can try with the following:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php include('autocomplete.php'); ?>;

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, 10));
        }
        minLength: 2 //search after two characters
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your autocomplete.php file?

Answer (score 0):

The file that contains your JS must be a PHP file. Something like my-script.php instead of the traditional .js extension

Comment: I have a fully working copy of this - however I am trying to limit the number of dropdowns. I dont want to apply a CSS height so I am trying to incorporate a function. The PHP source file is a JSON array.